# 'AutoScroll Listbox as You Type

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I tried to write a VB.Net code for a ListBox in which it AutoScroll the Listbox as You Type;
SO it will go, select and highlight the item with first similar few letters;
The code below works fine for the first time (i.e. when the form loads) but it stops working after this;
Any idea?

```
Public Class Form1

'AutoScroll Listbox as You Type 
Dim searchChars As String

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyUp
    searchChars += Chr(e.KeyValue)
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.FindString(searchChars)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Canada")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("USA")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("France")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Japan")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Belgium")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Bulgariaa")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("India")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Iraq")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Iran")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Ireland")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Malaysia")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Thailand")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Bangaladish")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Italy")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Republic of Whatever")
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    ListBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending characters here:

```
searchChars += Chr(e.KeyValue)
```

So if you first press `I` key then it finds `India`, but if you press again `I` key then `searchChars` will contains `II` then it has nothing to find 'cause any Item starts with `II`, and, after this, you are not reseting the appended chars inside `searchChars`.

you can do this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
Handles ListBox1.KeyUp

    sender.SelectedIndex = 
           sender.FindString(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue), sender.SelectedIndex)

End Sub
```

> UPDATE:

Another way to do this (appending chars):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
Handles ListBox1.KeyUp

    Static SearchPattern As String
    SearchPattern &= CStr(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue))

    Dim FindIndex As Integer = 
        sender.FindString(SearchPattern)

    If FindIndex = -1 Then
        SearchPattern = CStr(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue))
        sender.SelectedIndex = sender.FindString(SearchPattern)

    Else
        sender.SelectedIndex = FindIndex

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello ElektroStudios; this works fine if your items in alphabetical order; but mine are not; I've tried to combine the  searchChars += Chr(e.KeyValue) with the   sender.SelectedIndex  but it didn't work;  is there a way to combine them??

Comment: @Abbas1999 I've used exactlly the same code of your example, the same listbox with the same unsorted items and it works as expected. Did you really tried it?, no matters the alphabetical order, notice that I'm using the StartIndex parameter of FindString method.

Comment: yes ElektroStudios; I've added your changes to my code; it worked perfect for the first letter, but I cannot combine it with the [searchChars += Chr(e.KeyValue)]; I wanr if I click "Ire" it goes to "Ireland", Not "India" or "Iraq"...

Comment: but if you press "ire" first will go to the item starting with "I", next to item starting with "IR" and finally goes to item starting with "IRE". It goes char by char. How do you expect to wait for a string and when to decide that the string should be searched if you are handling a key event?.

Comment: ElektroStudios; this is great; it worked finally after few wasted hours; I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Abbas1999 I'm glad to be of help, but I would like to remember you that if my answer solved the problem then you should mark it as accepted as SO rules says. thanks for comment!

Comment: Hi ElektroStudios 'I am more than happy to do this' but I am new here and not sure how to mark it; I will look around to find out how...